# No "beq" or "bne" instruction in ARMv7-M manual?

Tags: arm, armv7, cortex-m

I'm working on a STM32l475 micro-controller which runs a Cortex-M4 processor and ARM/Thumb instruction sets. I see (from `objdump`) that there are `beq.n` and `bne.n` instructions generated in the binary of an ARM program (I added the `-mthumb` flag when compile the program). However, I don't find these branch instructions in the latest [ARMv7-M](https://web.archive.org/web/20190417194428/https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0403/eb/DDI0403E_B_armv7m_arm.pdf) manual.

Can anyone tell me the reason? And what are the instructions available in the manual that are equivalent to these two branch instructions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`beq` and `bne` are conditional branches; in other words, they are conditional versions of the *unconditional* branch `b`. `eq` and `ne` are two different condition codes; they are described in section A7.3. `beq` means *branch if equal* and `bne` means *branch if not equal*.

The `b` branch instruction has two different encodings in Thumb mode. The encoding you're seeing is probably encoding T1 described in section A7.7.12:

> `B<c> <label>`
>
> ```
> 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
>  1  1  0  1 [-<cond>--] [--------imm8---------]
> ```

In this encoding, the condition code (like `eq` or `ne`) is encoded directly into the instruction, in bits 8-11. The disassembly from objdump displays the condition code in place of `<c>` above. So using the condition code table in section A7.3, you would encode `beq` as `11010000[imm8]`.